# Regex matching MAC address

Tags: python, regex, mac-address

I'm trying to get all valid MAC addresses from this string:

```
00:1e:68:51:4f:a9    <-> 00:1a:8c:10:ad:30          9       540       8       336      17       876    90.457130000       198.0143
```

I've tried this and a few other regexes:

```
^([0-9A-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$
```

**Regex 101 here:**

https://regex101.com/r/kI5nI6/1

I can't figure out why I'm not getting any matches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You have to remove the anchors `^` and `$`
- You have to add `a-z` in your character set.. or make the searches case insensitive with `(?i)` (i modifier)

Following will work:

```
([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kI5nI6/3)

Comment: But in your demo you're matching the last two bytes in each MAC address. It doesn't seem like it's matching the whole MAC address

Comment: It is matching whole mac address.. but the colors are because of the capture groups `( )` you are using.. check demo now..

Answer (score 2):

The anchors `^` and `$` say to only match strings that are MAC addresses, not the parts within strings that are MAC addresses. Also, your regex uses capital letters (A-F), but the MAC addresses in that string are lowercase. Are you doing a case insensitive search (if using the `re` module, that would be `re.IGNORECASE`)? Try turning on case-insensitive search or add "a-f" after the A-F.

On a side note, there is no reason to include the `:` in brackets (`[:]`), because that means "match any one of this one character". You can just use `:` directly.

With case insensitive off you should be able to use this:

```
([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})
```

With case insensitive on:

```
([0-9A-F]{2}:){5}([0-9A-F]{2})
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something but looking here: https://regex101.com/r/aQ9vX0/1 your regex is not matching both complete mac addresses

Comment: That's because you also need the "global" flag (the 'g' in the textbox to the right of the regex). That makes it so that it searches for more than one match in one line: https://regex101.com/r/aQ9vX0/2